# include.param as the Foo in site.tags.Foo

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I use the following code in `_includes/last_two_foo_posts.html` to display the `title` of the last two Jekyll posts which have the tag "Foo":

```
{% assign posts = site.tags.Foo %}
{% for post in posts limit:2 %}
  {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'd like to refactor the code so that I can call the `include` with a

```
{% include last_two_posts.html param="Foo" %}
```

Is there a way in Liquid to use something like `{{ include.param }}` for the `Foo` in the  `site.tags.Foo` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### _includes/post_by_tag.html

```
{% assign posts = site.tags.[include.tag] %}
{% for post in posts limit: include.number %}
  <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

#### using it

```
{% include post_by_tag.html tag='Rails' number=3 %}
```

Et hop !